How to modify Brave-browser parameters for instances run by Selenium?
I am testing selenium. The Brave-browser is launched with the following code extract:
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome(browser_executable_path='/usr/bin/brave-browser', headless=False)
driver.get(LOGIN_URL)
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element('xpath','//input[@name="email"]').send_keys(MY_EMAIL)

At first launch, Brave-browser tells me the web site is unsecured, I assume just after driver.get(LOGIN_URL). Then I put it in the white list, but unexpectedly, it is like Brave-browser parameters are reseted when launched from Selenium the next time.
When I use the Brave-browser as a standard user, I don't have this problem, the white list remains as configured.
Is there a way to make the Brave-browser settings persistent over selenium uses, possibly by redeclaring the web site in the white list through driver in the code?
I have tested these additions:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
driver = uc.Chrome(browser_executable_path=browser_executable_path, headless=False, options=chrome_options)

It starts good, the site is not blocked, I access to the login page, sets the login and password, then it says it is wrong, Brave cuts the web connexion and resets my parameters!
